# How to replace Date object

Tags: gwt

```java
Date date = new Date();
int lastMonth = date.getMonth();
int lastYear = 1900 + date.getYear();
```

I have this code in my GWT project but a lot of method of java.util.Date is deprecated, 22/33 methods.
So I want to use Calendar/GregorianCalendar : it does not work. It said there is a missing package.

What is the best practice to replace these line of code with a not deprecated code ?

Comment: You're specifically talking about client side code, right?

Comment: @RohitJain GWT is a toolkit from google that translates Java into javascript so that both server and client can be written in the same language. The client side code base (the one translated into javascript) is fairly restricted, for instance the Calendar class is not made available.

Comment: @Dunes. Thanks for the info. didn't have the idea.

Comment: @blessedgeek see my comment below on Adriaan Koster'answer... :oP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't.

`java.util.Calendar` is almost impossible to emulate, and has a way too high overhead. `java.util.Date`, while far from ideal, is the closest to JavaScript's `Date`, so it's the one you should use in *GWT world*.

[JSR 310](http://threeten.sf.net) is promising (don't know how well it could be emulated though, and with how much overhead compared to `java.util.Date`) but isn't there yet.

There's also Joda Time (from the same author as JSR 310, JSR 310 aims at bringing Joda Time to the JDK along with fixing some of its early design mistakes), but most GWT ports have long been abandonned.

In the end: use `java.util.Date`.

And if you find the deprecation warnings annoying, then suppress them: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecated")`.

Comment: Dommage ! I will add this @SuppressWarnings("deprecated") so. GWT is only use in France ? Each I aks something about GWT, only get answer from French... :oD

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Date is not deprecated! Admittedly many methods of it are (like getMonth and getYear) which I try to avoid using. In the case of GWT you can use something like [DateTimeFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) to do date formatting and parsing.

Comment: `java.util.Date is not deprecated` : just have a look to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/Date.html. Of course the class is not deprecated but 22/33 methods are deprecated : for me it means : "do not use this class, no more".

Comment: java.util.Date is still used in many places as a handy timestamp wrapper. For example java.sql.Timestamp is a subclass of Date. The formatting/manipulation API Date contains has been deprecated but the class has definitely not.

Comment: Just write an other way what I have writed... So I know ! May my question was edited to say so.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense to me at all.